# Container with align-items: center is moving when an item switch its height but ONLY when the container isn't fully visible on the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div in `display: flex` which contains another div with some text content and a ul. The items are aligned vertically with `align-items: center`. When i hover an item in the list, the content changes and every text has a different size.

But here it is, everything looks fine when all the container is visible on the page but if I scroll down until the top of the container is out of the viewport then the container starts to expand or reduce. It can be seen when it switches to a content with more or less lines than the previous one.

I made this GIF for a better understanding of the problem : https://gifyu.com/image/STtIP

And I recreated the bug here : https://codepen.io/lorenzofg/pen/JjLxJBj

I could fix the height of the content div but I would like to avoid that and keep a dynamic height to properly center the text.

Does someone know what's going on or can tell me if what i wanna do is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

- replace height: 100%; with min-height:100vh; in the container class.
- remove width or replace width: 20%; with width: 50%; in the content class.

Comment: It's still moving :/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).